# Why am I getting an error when using the UPDATE function with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```py
SQLQuery="UPDATE Players SET [Player Name] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Player Name], 'Christian', 'Chris') , 'Reece', 'John')"  
df = pd.read_sql(SQLQuery, sqlcon)
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

I ran the same SQL code in SSMS and it works perfectly fine. Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just execute the query, not try to read the result into a dataframe, since there are no results for an `UPDATE` query.

```
SQLQuery="UPDATE Players SET [Player Name] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Player Name], 'Christian', 'Chris') , 'Reece', 'John')"  
sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.read_sql is meant to retrieve data from a sql database, your query is trying to make an update in the database.

For doing a simple update you can use SQLAlchemy execute, From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html) the syntax is the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text("select username from users"))
    for row in result:
        print("username:", row['username'])
```

There are other possible syntax and styles if you use for instance an ORM etc.